# Javascript window.getSelection() length 0 while using querySelector

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the selected text using **window.getSelection.getRangeAt(0)**
This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          function Selected(){
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
              alert(range);
            content = range.cloneContents();
            var select = content.querySelectorAll('span');
            alert(select.length);
          }
          </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <span style="font-size:45px"  onmouseup="Selected()" id="idNo1">This is some text</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**alert(select.length);** IS ALWAYS 0 can someone help me out with this. ThankYou. but range contains the selected text.

Comment: Yea i know that . when i select "this is some text" range contains that but not able to that using querySelecctorAall

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this to get the selected string length?
alert(range) is doing range.toString()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          function Selected(){
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
              // to get the text ( it does range.toString() )
              alert(range);
              // to get the text length
              alert(range.toString().length);
              // to get the id of the startNode
              alert(range.startContainer.parentNode.id);
          }
          </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <span style="font-size:45px"  onmouseup="Selected()" id="idNo1">This is some text</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we also get the id of the selected text using this method?

Comment: you can by range.startContainer.parentNode

Comment: alert(range.startContainer.parentNode.id); it gets you the id of the startSelection node

Answer (score 1):

The answer and some useful related bits too:

The **selected text**:

```
window.getSelection().toString();//pa'rtially selected tex't.
window.getSelection().toString().length;//20, length of the selected text.
```

The text in the **anchor node** (where the initial dragging of text is *started*, can be on either left *or* right side:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode;//Node text, NOT selection text.
window.getSelection().anchorNode.length;//Length of node's text, not selection.
```

The text in the **focus node** (where the initial dragging of text is *ended*, can be on either left *or* right side:

```
window.getSelection().focusNode;//Node text, NOT selection text.
window.getSelection().focusNode.length;//Length of node's text, not selection.
```

The common ancestor (effectively the `parentNode`) of the selected text:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer
```

Delete selected text:

```
window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument();
```